# Changing the python version of new anaconda to existing python version

Tags: python, anaconda

I recently installed Anaconda with python 3.7 on my windows system. Prior to this I already had python 3.6 installed on my system. I just needed to check if there is any possibility to change my python version from new 3.7 to python 3.6 which is already been installed. According to my understanding changing python version in Anaconda is done using

```
conda install python=<version>
```

But this will install new version of python. I do not want to install new version but I just want to activate an existing version of python.

Can anyone please help me out with this.

Thanks in advance